# Delay restart on failure for systemd service

Tags: systemd, services

My systemd service file correctly restarts my executable if it fails with a non-success exit code.  My service file contains:

```
SuccessExitStatus=0 129 200
Restart=on-failure
```

Since my executable depends on the presence of a device, it might shutdown right after start if the device is missing (causing non-stop restarts).  I would like my service to try to restart once per minute, not non-stop.  Is there a way to set a delay/gap/interval for restarts based on failure?  I found this but one website says this only applies for restarting at regular intervals:

```
RestartSec=

Configures the time to sleep before restarting a service (as configured with Restart=). Takes a unit-less value in seconds, or a time span value such as "5min 20s". Defaults to 100ms.
```

Comment: Just to confirm.  You want no restart on success (`0`, `129`, `200`).  Then you want a 1-min restart in response to another code (i.e. `1`), and an immediate restart otherwise?  If you don't mind a 1-min restart in any failure-case, then `RestartSec=` is appropriate for you.

Comment: No, restart on failure (exit code is not equal to 0/129/200) otherwise don't restart

Comment: Ah, `Restart=on-failure` with `RestartSec=60`and `SuccessExitStatus=0 129 200` sounds perfect for you.

Comment: Another thought. Since this service "depends" on a device, you could make this "unit" depend on another "unit" representing that device. Example: If that device creates a path. Then make a *.path unit that monitors the path and has a relationship with your service. This will trigger your service when that path is available. Then you don't need to worry about polling constantly for the device's existence.

Comment: @Stewart I didn't think of that - excellent solution thanks.  And I'll try restartsec (I thought that did something else)